# binding combobox to a stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

i have in my database to tables like this:
Address(A_id,city,street)
customer(c_id,a_id,name,...)
and I've made a silverlight application and puts two 'combobox' controls like this:

```
....
  <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,5,0,0" Name="comboBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />....
```

i want to bind one combobox to 'city' column and the selected value to 'A_id'
i used a 'silver-light enabled WCF service' but i don't know how to bind the combobox to a stored procedure that gives me all the addresses and how to get the selected value from selected item..
note:i'm newbie to silverlight and data binding.

Comment: If you are using Entity Framwork, you can bing the combobox to a list of a result object.

Answer (score -1):

Bit of an open ended question.  Not too sure where to begin.  For a start you would not bind a combobox directly to a stored procedure.  You will need to expose a method on a WPF service that returns all the data you need to populate the combobox.  The WPF service method would then potentially communicate with a domain/business object that makes a request to a data layer.  The data layer has the responsibility of talking to your database and retrieving the required data.  Now I'm not sure of the technology stack that you are using but there are multiple options for implementing the domain/data layers e.g. NHibernate, Entity Framework etc etc.  I think you need to sit down and spend a bit of time on your architectual design.  Once you have sorted that out we can start to talk about Combobox controls and how to retrieve selected items etc.